# Food Prepared by Following a Recipe

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call the **food** that we made/prepared by following a **recipe**?

It doesn't have to be a `single word` actually. I just want a shorter term for that.

Comment: perhaps *reliable*?

Comment: maybe not suitable, I want to make a clause like `Share your ...`, Is `work` suitable for my case?

Comment: If you're looking for something like "work", maybe "efforts" fits the bill?

Comment: Aprian, saying *How do we call* is awkward and unnatural. A common and natural wording would be ***What** do we call*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any food which is prepared following a recipe is normally called a *dish*.

**Dish** is defined as *A particular variety or preparation of food served as part of a meal.*

- *fresh fish dishes*
- *pasta was served as a main dish*

### Edit:

In the light of @Aprian's comment:

> If I use "Share your recipes", would it suggest that they are sharing
> their own recipes? I want them to share the picture of dishes that
> they prepared.

may I suggest that either of the following the phrases could be used:

- Post your dishes online
- Submit your photos of dishes
- Share the end results of your culinary efforts by sending us your photos.

  <sup>(Not pithy perhaps but it is clear)</sup>

[Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=post+your+dishes&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=HW7GUqqLMuPByQPK24DICg&ved=0CEoQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=652#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=%22post+your+dishes%22&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=7bSZQ-YuW17IhM%3A%3Bk45W_Ao0GwLVRM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fcdn.observedtrials.net%252Fvb%252Fattachments%252Ff33%252F30658d1387405994-gourmet-cooking-home-post-your-dishes-1473038_631903303534294_810290780_n.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.observedtrials.net%252Fvb%252Ff33%252Fgourmet-cooking-home-post-your-dishes-34706%252Findex25.html%3B720%3B960) seems to back me up on *post your dishes*.

Comment: Wouldn't you also call food that was prepared using improvisation a *dish*.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, any food which involves adding ingredients and any form of preparation is a *dish*. The fact that it is improvised still means there was a procedure leading to the end product.

Comment: So I guess whether this is a valid answer depends on whether the OP wanted a word to distinguish between a dish prepared following a recipe and an improvised dish (this was my interpretation) or just a word which means *dish*. Rereading the question, it's not completely clear.

Comment: I interpreted the OP asking for the name of the food prepared following a recipe.  The OP's example sentence: "share your *work*" is far too vague; *"share your dishes"* or "recipes" on the other hand, fits better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually I want them to share picture of the dishes that they prepared by following the recipes in my apps. So which word fits better?

Comment: @Aprian It can be "Share your recipes" which suggest that users contribute to the site by posting their favourite or best recipes online. Or "Post/Share pictures of your dishes" which means that users could take photos of the dishes thus prepared and share them online.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you can call it a *recipe*.

You would generally say:

> her recipe for lemon bars was delicious,

and not the longer alternatives:

> the lemon bars made by following her recipe were delicious,
>   the dessert made by following her recipe for lemon bars was delicious.

These alternatives are grammatical, and are in some sense more logical, but I don't think any native English speaker would use them.

Comment: That might suggest that you ate the piece of paper on which the recipe was written and found that to be delicious. I think I would say 'Her recipe for lemon bars proved delicious, when tried/used/put to effect/etc.'

Comment: @WS2: that's why I said the alternatives might be more logical. I wouldn't say *"the blueprints flew well"*; I'd say something like *"the blueprints produced a plane that flew well"*. But I don't see anything wrong with *"her recipe was delicious"*.

Comment: If I use `Share your recipes`, would it suggest that they are sharing their own recipes? I want them to share the picture of dishes that they prepared.

Comment: Actually, "share your recipes" would suggest sharing instructions for preparing your dishes. And "share your dishes" would suggest sharing the actual food. But "share pictures of your dishes/recipes" would work.

Answer (score 1):

I might use "as prescribed", or "as written", or "as described", or even "as directed".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the other answers. However, it seems like the OP's *What do we call the food that we made/prepared by following a recipe?* suggests that the OP wants an adjective that can be used in general. And for that, I would like to suggest **by-the-recipe** (in parallel to a common phrase *by the book*).

Its usage is also quite common on the web, though it is usually used to describe a person. For example,

> *My wife is a **by-the-recipe** baker.*
>   *I'm usually a **by-the-recipe** type of cook because my dad, who owned a restaurant, is a chef ...*
>   *If you are strictly a **by-the-recipe** person, you will enjoy it for the cultural notes and beautiful illustrations ...*

If you use someone else's recipes, *by-the-recipe* is a right word. But if the recipes are yours, then you might want to use the word *homemade* instead. Compare:

> *Jane is a great cook. You would be amazed by her **by-the-recipe** dishes this evening.*
>   *Does **homemade** food always taste better than shop-bought?*

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English, actually what I want is `noun` instead of `adj`. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Oh, please don't say that. It's not bad. It's all my fault that I misunderstood you. And for that, I'm sorry. I still hope that the answer could be of some uses for you.